# spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency error

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

I am using new version of Spring boot - 1.5.7.
But , when I create new spring starter project with jpa dependency,
I got strange error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

Could anybody help me:
Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-11</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo-11</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Comment: post your application.properties file

Comment: For the purpose of testing the problem, I create an new spring starter  project with jpa dependency, so my application.properties file is empty. But I worked with oracle database otherwise, and when I add oracle dependency it give me the same error.  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
   <version>12.1.0.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a database in your dependencies.
If a database was found, spring boot auto-configures your datasource for you.

See this example, which includes a h2database.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: I added oracle dependency <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
   <version>12.1.0.1.0</version>
  </dependency>   , but it gives me the same error. I tried alse with mysql : <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>, but it alse give me the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your database related info in the application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

And you need to put the database dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

this is how it's listed in the official site for mysql, you can try with your database of choice.

Comment: I added oracle dependency  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
   <version>12.1.0.1.0</version>
  </dependency> (before that I imported oracle ojdbc7.jar into maven repository).   Also, I changed application.properties file: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@___________:1521/******
spring.datasource.username=*******
spring.datasource.password=*******  , but it gives me the same error again

Comment: if you can post your whole project on git or something i can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the database in dependencies in the file pom.xml according to the database used in the application.yml file:

1. application.yml file:

```html
datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your-database
  username: user
  password: password
```

2. pom.xml file:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```